# redirect newly registering woo customers?

Tags: php, woocommerce, registration

**1.** Hi all. I'm not sure if this is working as expected or if i've created a specific issue, but i've created two separate custom Login and Register pages and forms for Woocommerce, and also set up a few basic redirects for logging in users, logging out users, and - as a failsafe - a redirect to a /logged-in page for already-logged-in users who somehow get to the /login or /register pages by mistake.

Here's the code redirecting already-logged-in users away from the /login and /register pages:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'edts_logged_in_redirect' );
function edts_logged_in_redirect() {
    if ((is_page('login') || is_page('register')) && is_user_logged_in() && wc_current_user_has_role('customer')) {
        wp_redirect( 'https://example.com/logged-in', 301 ); 
        exit;
    }
}
```

Here's the problem: in testing, users who a registering on the /register page are being redirected by my code to the /logged-in page as soon as they click the 'Register' button.

Sure i can work with it, i can make a nice friendly "You're registered and logged in, what do you want to do now?" page, and i can see WHY the redirect might work this way - is_page('register') - but is there something i'm not considering, and how could i redirect these new Customers to a /success page if i wanted to?

**2.** About this /register page, too, the option to set a password is on, so there's a password field, but NO show-password-input to show the password they're setting.

Here's the password input field code:

```
<input type="password" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" name="password" id="reg_password" autocomplete="new-password" />
```

'woocommerce-Input' is there, so i'm not sure what the problem is.

thanks in advance for any help and advice!